# Why is an action-independent baseline required to reduce variance?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients, actor-critic-methods, reinforce

I'm learning policy gradient methods. I encountered the REINFORCE algorithm with variance reduction with a baseline. I see we can use a constant or state-dependent function (e.g value function) but not an action-value function as a baseline.

Is there any intuition behind this?

I saw some papers claimed that an action-dependent baseline improves the performance compared to baselines that use only state information. One example is: [Variance Reduction for Policy Gradient with Action-Dependent Factorized Baselines](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.07246v1.pdf) (2018) by Cathy Wu et al.

Comment: Can you please explain which paper/resource claims that you need "an action-independent baseline to reduce the variance"? You only say that we can use a constant or state-dependent function as the baseline and that a paper used an dependent baseline and that improved the performance (what do you mean by "performance", btw? And do they mention anything about the variance?).